# Filtrar resultados con las respuesta del formulario y mostrar mensaje si no obtiene resultados en Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

He creado un formulario donde está lleno de checkbox con opciones a marcar para filtrar un resultado.

```
<form name="form" action="{{ route('web.filtrarEtiquetas') }}" method="get" id="filtrador">
   @csrf
   <div id="accordion2">
      @foreach ($categorias as $item)
        <div class="card card_no_border">
          <div class="card-header card_h" id="headingOne2">
             <h5 class="mb-0">
             <a class="btn btn-link btn_collapse" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#filtros{{ $item->id }}" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="filtros{{ $item->id }}">
              <span>{{ $item->name }}</span> <i class="fas fa-plus-square"></i>
             </a>
             </h5>
           </div>
                
           <div id="filtros{{ $item->id }}" class="collapse {{ $loop->first ? 'show' : '' }}" aria-labelledby="headingOne2" data-parent="#accordion2">
             <div class="card-body">
               <div class="row subcategorias">
                 @foreach ($item->etiquetas as $sub)
                   <div class="col-4">
                     <div class="form-check form-check-inline margenChecks">
                        <input class="form-check-input aligned juegos" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox{{ $sub->id }}" name="etiquetas[]" value="{{ $sub->id }}">
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox{{ $sub->id }}">{{ $sub->name }} <span class="cantidadPro">({{ $sub->productos_count }})</span></label>
                     </div>
                    </div>
                  @endforeach
                </div>
               </div>
               </div>
           </div>
          @endforeach
        </div>
      </form>
        
      <div class="text-center margenBtnGuardar">
         <button class="btnguardar" id="btn_filtrar" disabled="true">GUARDAR</button>
      </div>
```

En lugar de mandar el formulario con el botón he creado una función en jquery, primero para comprobar si hay algún checkbox marcado, si es así habilito el botón de guardar, le pongo una animación al botón y a los segundos envío la petición al controlador.

**Ruta**

```
Route::get('/filtrar-etiquetas', [Web::class, 'filtrarEtiquetas'])->name('web.filtrarEtiquetas');
```

**Controlador**

```
public function filtrarEtiquetas(Request $request)
    {
        $productos = [];
        foreach($request->etiquetas as $item){
            $productos[] = Productos::where('etiqueta_id', $item)->get();
        }

        if(auth()->guest()){
            return view('filtrar')->with(['productos' => $productos, 
                                          "categorias" => $this->categorias]);
        }else{
            $likes = Like::select('entrie_id')->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->get();
            $likeArr = Arr::flatten($likes->toArray());

            return view('filtrar')->with(['productos' => $productos, 
                                          "categorias" => $this->categorias,
                                          "likes"=> $likeArr]);
        }
    }
```

Aquí es donde se me complica, como recibo un array con los valores marcados por el cliente, hice un foreach para obtener los productos con esas `id`, hice también esto para guardarlo en un arreglo `$productos = [];`

El problema de esto es que me guarda también los que no tienen producto.

Luego en la vista:

```
@foreach ($productos as $item)
    @foreach ($item as $articulos)
      .......
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

De forma que no comprendo aunque traiga arreglos vacíos, solo me imprime los que sí traen contenido.

A pesar de que creo que no es la forma correcta de hacer esto y me gustaría saber cómo hacerlo mejor, es que de este modo si no obtiene resultados no tengo forma de mostrar un mensaje en la vista ya que siempre trae algo aunque sea vacío.

Comment: No sé si entiendo bien tu lógica, per creo que sería más fácil y eficiente con un whereIn. Algo así `$productos = Productos::whereIn('etiqueta_id', $request->etiquetas)->get();`

Comment: Es estupendo, no se me paso por la cabeza. Serias tan amable de publicar una respuesta y el porque funciona y así la marco para otra persona que tenga el mismo problema?? Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según entiendo, en el request te llega un array con las id de etiquetas que se desprenden de los checkbox marcados en el formulario.
Entonces en `$request->etiquetas`, tendrías algo como `[1, 3, 7, 11]` por ejemplo.

Si bien es técnicamente posible iterar sobre los elementos de ese array para consultar la BD para cada elemento, esto no es eficiente, ya que tendrías una consulta por cada elemento, y si son pocos tal vez no se note, pero no es escalable si la cantidad de elementos del array aumenta. Y como sugerencia, aunque no siempre sea posible hacerlo de otra manera, siempre hay que desconfiar de las consultas a la BD dentro de un loop, pues es intenso para la BD y las consultas disminuyen la eficiencia de la aplicación.

Dicho eso, y como la consulta es relativamente simple: sólo quieres consultar los productos que su campo `etiqueta_id` coincida con alguno de los elementos del array que llega en el request, puedes echar mano a la cláusula [`whereIn()`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#basic-where-clauses).

> El método `whereIn` verifica que el valor de una columna dada esté contenido dentro de la matriz dada.

NOTA IMPORTANTE (por lo que mencioné anteriormente, aunque no aplique a este caso):

> Si está agregando un gran array de enteros a su consulta, el método `whereIntegerInRaw` se pueden usar para reducir en gran medida el uso de la memoria.

Entonces una solución a tu problema de que en el arreglo resultante de las consultas traiga elementos vacíos (pues no hay resultados para alguna etiqueta) puede ser usar el método `whereIn()`, que te devolverá una colección sin elementos vacíos, y que además hará más eficiente tu código.

```php
public function filtrarEtiquetas(Request $request)
{
    $productos = Productos::whereIn('etiqueta_id', $request->etiquetas)->get();

    if(auth()->guest()) {
        return view('filtrar')->with([
            'productos' => $productos, 
            "categorias" => $this->categorias,
        ]);
    }
    
    $likes = Like::select('entrie_id')->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->get();
    $likeArr = Arr::flatten($likes->toArray());

    return view('filtrar')->with([
        'productos' => $productos, 
        "categorias" => $this->categorias,
        "likes"=> $likeArr
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Que gran explicación! Brillante... gracias